# Download a excel file and saved into Folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, urllib

I am trying download the excel file and save in folder ,

**Below the code.**

```
import urllib.request

outfilename = "test.xls"

xls = "https://api.myntrainfo.com/api/diy-cataloguing/attributeSheet/downloadStatusDetails?q=404144&filterStatus=null"

url_of_file = xls
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_of_file, outfilename)
```

**while executing getting below Error . can you please check help me .**

```
Error:
 raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you can access the excel sheet only when u login to the website. You can't do it just by opening the url. Instead, you can login to the webpage using `selenium python` and then try downloading the excel sheet.